# Woocommerce - Display Lowest Price on Category (Archive) Page Only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, price

I'm trying to display the lowest price instead of the price range on the category pages while continuing to display the price range on the individual product pages.

I found this answer from someone else's question:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2);

function custom_variation_price( $price, $product ) {

    $price = '';

    if ( !$product->min_variation_price || $product->min_variation_price !== $product->max_variation_price ) {
        $price .= '<span class="from">' . _x('From', 'min_price', 'woocommerce') . ' </span>';
        $price .= woocommerce_price($product->get_price());
    }

    return $price;
}
```

And it works, but when I put the code in `functions.php`, it applies to the whole site. I only want it to apply to the category pages.

Also, when I use this code, items with only one price end up with no price being displayed.

What can I do?

Here's a screenshot of what I mean:
[Screenshot of current category page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da4cV.png)

Comment: I have updated my code with some explanations… I hope this time it will work.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec, I can't seem to find your answer?

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right then you just need to display the minimal price whenever there's a range of prices. So basically you need to change the `$price`'s HTML only if product's minimal price is set (if it's not set then the product has a single price and no change is needed). I also included the check for whether it's a category page. Here's the code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2);
function custom_variation_price( $price, $product ) {
    if ( ! empty($product->min_variation_price) && is_product_category() ) {
        $price = '<span class="from">' . _x('From', 'min_price', 'woocommerce') . ' </span>';
        $price .= woocommerce_price($product->get_price());
    }

    return $price;
}
```